# AsyncTask not running asynchronously

Tags: android, android-asynctask

The following were supposed to be the same if I am not mistaking.
Using **AsyncTask**:

```
private class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return NetConnection.getRecordData(mUserId, mUserPassword);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        parseJson(result);
    }
}
```

Using a **Thread**:

```
    new Thread( new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            String res = NetConnection. getRecordData(mUserId, mUserPassword);
            parseJson(res);

        }
    }).start();
```

But when uploading a file, the AsyncTask runs `synchronously` while the Thread run `asynchronously`(in parallel).
Why is so? Why AsyncTask behaves like this? Isn't AsyncTask supposed to run asynchronously?
I am little confused so I need your help.
This is how I invoke the GetDataTask:

```
new GetDataTask().execute()
```

I prefer using AsyncTask but it is not doing the job for me. Please refer to my [early question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15468563/1503155) for more details

Comment: how are you invoking the `AsyncTask`?..

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar new LoginTask().execute()

Comment: They _should_ run asynchronously. How do you understand that they are running synchronously? Do they block UI thread?

Comment: are you invoking them from UI thread?

Comment: @Alpay, because in the AsyncTask case I get the response only after the file finishes uploading.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of 4.x calling 2 AsyncTasks will cause them to be executed serially.

One way to fix this is using the following code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
  myTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
}
else {
  myTask.execute();
}
```

You can read more at: http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/04/20/asynctask-threading-regression-confirmed.html

Comment: Yeah I know! But I can not decide yet if I should award it to you or to @Praful Bhatnagar

Comment: god damn this drove me up the wall, thank you so much for posting this answer

Comment: Thanks.. saved my time

Answer (score 3):

Ok following are the notes from the [official java doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)...

> **Order of execution**
>
> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single
>   background thread.  Starting with [DONUT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#DONUT), this was changed to a pool of
>   threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with
>   [HONEYCOMB](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#HONEYCOMB), tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common
>   application errors caused by parallel execution.
>
> ```
> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke
> ```
>
> [executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[])](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29)  with [THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR).

SO if you invoke two AsyncTask together.. they would not be executed in parallel (exception is donut, encliar and gingerbread)... You can use `executeOnExecutor` to execute them in `parallel`...

Comment: Can you post this answer here so I can accept it there http://stackoverflow.com/q/15468563/1503155?

Answer (score 2):

From your code we can see you have called `parseJson(result);` in `onPostExecute()` of AsyncTask which runs in **MainUIThread** of Applications. So at that point your code runs Synchronously..

Put `parseJson(result);` method in `doInBackGround()` Which runs only in other worker thread.

While you have called same thing in `Thread`. So both

```
String res = NetConnection. getRecordData(mUserId, mUserPassword);
parseJson(res);
```

Runs in other worker thread out of **MAinUiThread** on which you experienced Asynchronously.

Note:

But be sure your `parseJson(res);` **doesn't update UI** while it is in `doInBackground(`).

Comment: I tested this, but somehow the behavior is the same. I get response only after the file upload is finished. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that actual problem is not in file uploading but in `parseJson` method.

In your `Thread` example you parsing Json in separate thread while in `AsyncTask` case you parsing Json in UI thread.